# Javascript datepicker not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, safari, datepicker

It's me again... Finally able to pass a date to my date to my object with javascript date picker, I'm not able to make it work on Safari...

This is my javascript :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy' });
    });
    $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }
        var valid = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('MM/dd/yy', value);        // Works on Mozilla FireFox
        }
        catch (err) {
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/MM/yy', value);    // Works on Google Chrome
            } catch (err) {
                    valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    });
</script>
```

and this is the call :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date, "{0:dd/MM/yy}", new { @class = "date" })
```

How can I make it work on this ... Safari please ?

Edit : if needed this is my culture in web.config :

`<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR" />`

Comment: are you using windows safari?

Comment: @Zamboney    yes I'm testing on windows safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as part of the response i get from @mrpixel6 the problem is that you are using windows safari

window safari is not supported sice 2012 [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history).

check out the [Browser Support _ jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/) and you can see that the safari version need to be gather then 5. so that its not support on safari windows version

hope its help :)

Comment: you can try by using visual machine that have osx on you computer or maybe using https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Ok Thank you ! But can I supposed that if it's working on last firefox and chrome version it will work on last Safari version ? ^^''

Comment: Yeah ^^' Thank you for the help